# Using Unity to Register MVC Types That Don't Exist (Yet)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, unity-container

The `UnityMvcActivator` is called right out of the gate when starting my MVC application, and it instantiates, configures, and sets the container to the DependencyResolver:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(UnityConfig.Container));
```

Which immediately registers all the types via:

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterMvcComponents();
}
```

...but I'm trying to register types that aren't created until a little further down the road:

```
public static IUnityContainer RegisterMvcComponents(this IUnityContainer container)
{
    var lifetimeManager = new HierarchicalLifetimeManager();

    container.RegisterInstance<HttpSessionStateBase>(
        new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session), lifetimeManager);
    container.RegisterInstance<HttpContextBase>(
        new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current), lifetimeManager);
    container.RegisterInstance<HttpServerUtilityBase>(
        new HttpServerUtilityWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Server), lifetimeManager);
    container.RegisterInstance(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity, lifetimeManager);

    return container;
}
```

I can't get the container back from the `DependencyResolver` when I finally make it to my OWIN `Startup` class - which is where all the other initialization is taking place - so how can I register these types?

**EDIT:**

Thinking I was clever, I tried adding some post-start action to the activator by adding this assembly directive and moving my configuration method call to the newly created method:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PostApplicationStartMethod(
           typeof(CCCS.Admin.Web.Ui.UnityMvcActivator), 
           nameof(CCCS.Admin.Web.Ui.UnityMvcActivator.PostStart))]

public static void PostStart() => UnityConfig.Container.RegisterMvcComponents();
```

... and that got me halfway, but the `User` and `Session` still aren't available.

Comment: Move all the registration into the Startup class. That or create you own custom resolver that exposes the container. That being said passing around the container is usually considered a code smell. If its just for the purpose described above in terms of registering. As for accessing HttpContext related members, They wont be available on till a request is made. well after startup in the pipeline.

Comment: You would better off creating abstractions to access those implementation concerns. Then you can wrap HttpContext related concerns to be accessed in a deferred manner when the desired members are available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) related to your design, as all the `HttpContext` related members wont be available at startup.

You would better off creating abstractions to defer the access to those implementation concerns.

```
public interface IHttpContextAccessor {
    HttpContextBase HttpContext { get; }
}

public class HttpContextProvider : IHttpContextAccessor {
    public virtual HttpContextBase HttpContext {
        get {
            return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all those registrations can be replaced with the one abstraction which would provide access to all the other related types.

```
public static IUnityContainer RegisterMvcComponents(this IUnityContainer container) {
    var lifetimeManager = new HierarchicalLifetimeManager();

    container.RegisterType<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextProvider>(lifetimeManager);

    return container;
}
```

Note that the container should ideally only be accessed in the composition root of the application and not passed around as a dependency. That is seen as a code smell and an indicator that the design should be reviewed and refactored if possible.

When access is needed to `HttpContext` related members it is now a matter of injecting the accessor

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

public MyDependent(IHttpContextAccessor accessor) {
    this.accessor = accessor;
}

public void SomeMethodAccessedInAnAction() {
    var context = access.HttpContext; // HttpContextBase
    var session = context.Session; // HttpSessionStateBase
    var server = context.Server; // HttpServerUtilityBase
    var user = context.User; // IPrincipal
    //...
}
```